# Strange behaviour of ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following model:

```
public class EditUserViewModel : AddEditUserViewModelPartial
{
    public string OldUsername { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public bool? NewPasswordGenerated { get; set; }
}

public class AddEditUserViewModelPartial
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Username/Email")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
....

public class AddEditUserPartial
{
    public TypeOfForm Type { get; set; }
    public AddEditUserViewModelPartial Model { get; set; }
}

public enum TypeOfForm
{
    ADD,
    EDIT
}
```

Partial Name:

```
    @model CHFN.Models.AddEditUserPartial

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Model.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Model.UserName)
        </div>
    </div>
    ....
```

Edit User:

```
@model CHFN.Models.EditUserViewModel

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Edit the account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.HiddenFor(p => p.OldUsername)
    @Html.HiddenFor(p => p.UserId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(p => p.NewPasswordGenerated)
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.Partial("PartialAddEditUser",
            new CHFN.Models.AddEditUserPartial()
        {
            Type = CHFN.Core.TypeOfForm.EDIT,
            Model = new CHFN.Models.AddEditUserViewModelPartial() { UserName = Model.UserName, Fullname = Model.Fullname, Roles = Model.Roles, Password = Model.Password, ConfirmPassword = Model.ConfirmPassword }
        })
```

to EditUser (post) is went an empty OldUsername, UserId, NewPasswordGenerated. And, more surprised for me, if I remove Html.Partial("PartialAddEditUser",...) - then OldUsername, UserId, NewPasswordGenerated is not empty. Why it happens?

Comment: What does your Get and Post controller methods look like?

Comment: Get method - fill model, post method - get model ...

Comment: Could you update your post with the relevant code? Or at least the signatures of the methods?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you are using different models for the main view and the partial view.

Consider the following line in your partial view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Model.UserName, ...)
```

When you post the data back to an action that expect (I assume) `EditUserViewModel` as the input model, MVC will try to find a property named `Model` on `EditUserViewModel` (which is not there.), and set the `UserName` property on that.

The solution may be to simple not use the `AddEditUserPartial` class at all. The partial call may then look simply like this:

```
@Html.Partial("PartialAddEditUser", Model);
```

The partial view could then be simplified to the following (notice we use the exact same model, and thus get rid of the extra `.Model`):

```
@model CHFN.Models.EditUserViewModel

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
    </div>
</div>
....
```

Comment: problem was in inheritance. EditUserViewModel is inherited from AddEditUserViewModelPartial, the same class is used as property in AddEditUserPartial. But in anycase, thank you for triyng to solve my problem :)